# Upper bound on Gamma function

Tags: analysis, inequality, gamma-function

I am interested in providing an upper bound on the expression $\big(\Gamma(1+p/s)\big)^{1/p}$ where $p\geq 2$ and $0<s<1$. I want to prove that $\big(\Gamma(1+p/s)\big)^{1/p} \leq C_s p^{1/s}$ for some constant $C_s$ dependent solely on $s$.

I wish to utilize a [bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) from Stirling's approximation for factorials: $n!\leq en^{n+1/2}e^{-n}$. However, I'm not sure if it generalizes to the Gamma function. That is, I was wondering if we have $\Gamma(1+z) \leq e z^{z+1/2}e^{-z}$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$. I have not been able to find a reference for this.

Supposing this is true, we would then have
$$\Gamma(1+p/s) \leq e (p/s)^{p/s}(p/s)^{1/2}e^{-p/s} \leq C_sp^{1/2}(p/s)^{p/s}.$$
Hence, we have (I might have to treat the cases where $C_s\leq 1$ differently)
$$\big(\Gamma(1+p/s)\big)^{1/p} \leq C'_sp^{1/(2p)}p^{1/s} \leq C''_sp^{1/s}$$
since $p^{1/(2p)}$ is uniformly bounded for $p>0$.

Therefore, my question is whether the bound $\Gamma(1+z) \leq e z^{z+1/2}e^{-z}$ is true and, if yes, where can I find a proof or reference for it.

Comment: The approximation works for $\Gamma$. See any article on Stirling's approximation, including the Wikipedia page cited.

Comment: @Aruralreader are you referring to the expression $\Gamma(z) = \sqrt{2\pi/z}(z/e)^z (1+O(1/z))$?

Comment: That's the one @varpi. Will that work for you?

Comment: Yea I think so, since I don't really care for a constant out front. Thanks!

Comment: my pleasure and best of luck.

Comment: The eq found at (https://dlmf.nist.gov/5.6.E6) bounds the magnitude of the gamma function for complex $z$ in terms of the gamma function using only the real part of $z$. If the real part of $z$ is nonnegative you may then bound this upper bound using Stirling. Here is another formula that should also do the trick: https://dlmf.nist.gov/5.6.E9